# Prepare cakephp case when for order by clause

Tags: mysql, cakephp

i prepared an sql statement that fulfill my requirements but i need to convert that sql
  statement into cakePHP model find condition i dont know how to prepare that one please help 
  me

SQL Query :

```
select id,text,is_file,order from kmp_contents 
where parent_id=1873
order by case 
when is_file=1 then text
when is_file=0 then order
end asc;
```

Comment: what have you tried? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$this->KmpContent->find(
    'conditions' => array('KmpContent.parent_id' => 1873),
    'fields' => array('KmpContent.id', 'KmpContent.text', 'KmpContent.is_file', 'KmpContent.order'),
    'order' => array('KmpContent.case ASC', 'WHEN is_file=1 THEN KmpContent.text WHEN is_file=0 THEN KmpContent.order ASC')
);
```

The `order` key wraps the conditions provided in the supplied array around the `ORDER BY` statement.

If this doesn't work, you can always use [`Model::query()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) for complex queries.

Comment: Hi Andrei thank you for your Query it is working fine but fails in one case i.e if my display order exceeded by 10 it will retrive the data like this 1 10 11 12 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: I've encountered this behavior before. It doesn't relate to CakePHP, but to the sorting algorithm of the database engine you use. The type of ordering you are looking for is called natural sorting. In CakePHP, you can use `Hash::sort()` for this, by settings the `$type` parameter. You can read more here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::sort